# SQL Management studio автоподстановка

Tags: sql-server

Можно ли сделать так, что бы SQL Management studio при вводе ключевых слов, например `SELECT` открывала меню со список?

Например, я ввел `SEL`, а мне тут же `SELECT` отобразился.

Или подстановщик ограничен подстановкой названий полей и таблиц?

Answer (score 4):

Стандартный IntelliSense так не умеет, зато так умеют:

- [SQL Prompt](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) (not free)
- [ApexSQL Complete](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx) (free)
- [SQL Assistant](http://www.softtreetech.com/isql.htm) (not free)
- [SQL Complete](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/) (free)
- [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/) (free)

и другие помощники, с более объемным  списком можно ознакомиться [тут](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Management+Studio+(SSMS)/159134/) и [тут](http://sqlcom.ru/dba-tools/sql-server-management-studio-full-list-tools/).

Comment: Дополните список, если у вас есть богатый список.

Comment: @iluxa1810 готово.

Comment: Sql Assistant разве фришный?

Comment: @iluxa1810 раньше был бесплатный, поправил.